# Does double exclamation (!!) in C++ cost more CPU time?

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization

I know it's a trick to do boolean conversion. My question is primarily about resource cost when writing this way. Will complier just ignore the "!!" and do implicit boolean conversion directly?

Comment: Have you tried disassembling the output or measuring performance?

Comment: There are lots of compilers, each one is different. The only way to tell would be to test the compiler you are interested in. But, whatever the answer, the cost is **microscopic**, concentrate on writing clear code instead of worrying about tricks.

Comment: The cost, if any, is negligible nowadays. If it helps write more robust, stable, secure (...) code, use it.

Answer (score 2):

If you have any doubts you can check the generated assembly; noting at the assembly level there is no such thing as a boolean type anyway. So yes, it's probably all optimised out.

As a rule of thumb, code that mixes types therefore necessitating type conversions will run slower, although that is masked by another rule of thumb which is *write clear code*.

Answer (score 2):

It depends.

If you limit attention just to basic types that are convertible to `bool` and can be an operand of the `!` operator, then it depends on the compiler.    Depending on target system, the compiler may emit a sequence of instructions that gives the required effect, but not in the way you envisage.    Also, a given compiler may treat things differently, with different optimisation settings (e.g compiling for debugging versus release).

The only way to be sure is to examine the code emitted by the compiler.    In practice, it is unlikely to make much difference.   As others have commented, you would be better off worrying about getting your code clear and working correctly,than about the merits of premature optimisation techniques.   If you have a real need (e.g. the operation is in a hotspot identified by a profiler) than you will have data to understand what the need is, and identify realistic options to do something about it.    Practically, I would doubt there are many real-world cases where there would be any difference.

In C++, with user-defined types, all bets are off.   There are many possibilities, such as classes that have an `operator!()` that returns a class type, a class that has an `operator!()` but not an `operator bool()`.   The list goes on, and there are many permutations.   There are cases where the compiler would be incorrect in doing such a transformation (e.g. `!!x` would be expected to be equivalent to `x.operator!().operator!()`  but there is not actually a requirement (coding guidelines aside) for that sequence to give the same net effect as `x.operator bool()`).   Practically, I wouldn't expect too many compilers to even attempt to identify an opportunity in such cases - the analysis would be non-trivial, probably not give many practical benefits (optimising single instructions is rarely where the gains are to be made in compiler optimisation). Again, it is better for the programmer to focus on getting code clear and correct, rather than worrying about how the compiler optimises single expressions like this.  For example, if calling an `operator bool()` is intended, then it is better to provide that operator AND write an expression that uses it (e.g. `bool(x)`) rather than hoping the compiler will convert a hack like `!!x` into a call of `x.operator bool()`.